# Populate cross street name at intersections

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, modelbuilder, spatial-join, road

Just a follow up of an older post seen here:

[Python script/Model to populate cross street names at intersections](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37118/python-script-model-to-populate-cross-street-names-at-intersections)

I need to create a shapefile of Road segments with a "To_Road/s" and "From_Road/s" as tables in the attributes.

[image]

In essence I want to create a shapefile with *JP van niekerk street* segment name between *Piet retief street* and *Sarel Cilliers street*. all in their own field.

I used the Planarize tool to separate the roads into segments. I know it has something to do with spatial join and the FID but I can not figure this one out.

I am not proficient enough in ModelBuilder to build the model in the link.

Comment: Thanks. This has helped. In essence I want to create a shapefile with attributes ( x btwn x & x) but in their own fields. Direction does not matter.

Comment: Thank you again. Found this link through the previous link you posted but this does not work for some or other reason. Generates a lot of null values?

Comment: This turned out to be a lot more complicated than I thought it would be, so even as brief as possible it's still a long answer. It's a different approach than the one taken in the model you linked to (which I couldn't follow either). It's readily apparent that the ideal solution would use Python scripting and perhaps update that VBA script linked to in the original question you linked to. I may experiment with that other node based method I linked to and see what happens - I've not used it myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First thing first is clean up the data.

1) Use the UNSPLIT LINE tool with the dissolve field set to the street names.

2) Use the 'Plannerize tool' on the output at step 1 to create segments between each crossing

3) Used the 'intersect tool' to create points at each intersection. (Join Attributes set to FID_Only and the output type should be set to POINTS)

4) Use 'Delete Identical' on the point feature created in step 3.

5) Use Spatial join:

-Target feature is Points feature
-Join feature is road feature
-Join operation is JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE
-Remove all in the Field map of join feature and add a new output field named Intersections. Type = TEXT, Merge Rule = JOIN, Delimiter = ' & ', Add input field = Streetname.
-Match Option: Intersect

This should create a field in the point feature class where it lists all the street intersections name at a point.

6) Use "FEATURE VERTICES TO POINTS" tool and create a start and end point respectively from you street feature. Name the resulted layers "Start" and "End"

7) Use Spatial Join to join these layers created in step 6 to your intersections point layer separately,

Name the resulting layers START_SP and END_SP

-Target features: "start" and "end" layers separately, 
-Join feature: Street intersections point layer, 
-JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE, 
-Match Option: Intersect

8) Create "From" and "To" Fields in your Street Segments layer.

9) Use joins (NOT SPATIAL JOIN) : Join your segment feature to START_SP with (match FID to ORIG_FID)

10) Use field calculator to copy the field in "FROM" field created in step 8.

11) Remove the join and repeat step 9 with the END_SP feature.

This should result in a Line feature with all the intersecting street names in their respective field.

Note: The segment name will also be present in the FROM and TO fields. I still need to find a solution to remove the segment name from the FROM and TO fields. Any suggestions?

Comment: See link to clean attribute table: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/135890/clean-up-attributes/136051#136051

Comment: Note that if you like, you can [accept your own answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) after 48 hours. You can also edit your comment link into your answer to replace the final sentence.

Answer (score 3):

I don't consider this a complete solution as it relies on non-out-of-the-box tools and isn't fully tested. It also may require an Advanced license. For now I am removing the comments I made linking to questions with methods using the start and end nodes of the lines, as after some testing I'm not sure how to apply that to this problem (while at the same time needing a start/end attribute - see below).

1. The lines must be cleaned up prior to starting. You've already
   Planarized, which is one step, but you should also check for
   pseudo-nodes - cases where two segments of the same road meet
   without any other intersecting roads - because they will cause
   problems. Other things to watch for or which aren't handled well (if
   at all) include more than two streets with different names meeting
   at a junction and dead-end or cul-de-sac roads. Finally, it's always
   best to work on a copy of data and in this case that has an added
   benefit. There will be some field duplication, so the fewer fields
   you have to start with the easier the table will be to follow. I
   strongly suggest eliminating all fields except Name and if your data
   has one the unique road segement ID (note this is distinct from the
   OID/FID).
2. With everything as clean as you can get it, start with a Spatial
   Join. You'll be joining the road layer to itself (target and join
   features), join operation one-to-many, match option of intersect. To
   ease field recognition in the next steps, in the Field Map box
   rename the name field (or whatever your road name field is called)
   to SegName and the name_1 field to CrossName. Do the same for the
   segment ID field if there is one, and remove other fields (like
   length) from the field mapping. In the resulting layer, each road
   segment is duplicated once for every road segment touching it,
   including itself. Open up the attribute table and immediately delete
   the Join_Count field to get it out of the way. Then note that
   target_fid is the *original* OID of the segment being considered and
   join_fid the *original* OID of the segments that touch/intersect the
   target. The name fields are probably aliased to their original 'name' field name - you can right-click > properties them and make the alias match the new names.
3. With all that duplication, some cleanup is needed. Start with two
   Select by Attributes: first where target_fid = join_fid (the copy of
   itself) and then where SegName = CrossName (the copies created by
   the segments of the same road before and after this one). You can
   delete the results of each selection in turn (entering an Edit
   Session first of course). **Warning**: *pseudonodes cause the second
   selection to delete segments that do not touch other roads and will
   leave gaps/holes in both the road lines and the final attributes
   (there will be only one populated cross-street).* Also, in my sample data I have a case where I end up with a road segment that has the same cross street at *both* ends, and in my case it *isn't* an error - the cross street has an offset for a few blocks, so it really does hit the road in two places.
4. There's still some duplicate left, but it requires more advanced
   methods to eliminate. If you have an Advanced license, you can use
   the Delete Identical tool (note this directly modifies the data, not
   create an output layer). Any case where target_fid *and* CrossName
   field values match in two different rows is an unnecessary
   duplicate. Note that if target_fid is the same SegName will be as
   well, while join_fid will always be different even if CrossName is
   the same since two different segments of CrossName meet at either
   end of the segment in question. In fact at this point the join_fid field can be deleted and no longer serves a purpose. If you do not have an Advanced
   license, Summary Statisics can serve here by using target_fid and
   CrossName as CASE fields. However it will create a standalone table
   with no geometry, and some new additional fields to get rid of.

And this is where the solution breaks down. You should have a table now with theoretically only two rows for any given target_fid (possibly one if it's a dead end or more if you have three or more named streets coming together at one intersection). You can look at the table and see that each of the two rows gives you a cross street from one end or the other of the segment. The problem is getting those two row values into columns. I could think of two options that wouldn't work (Transpose Fields and Pivot Table), one that would be overly complex (iterative joins with a complicated where selection to match as many records as possible in steps), and two more that are feasible but require extra steps:

- There is a script in an answer at
  [Summary table with a field that shows components of each summarized record](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/85114/) which can combine the
  two CrossName field values from the matching rows and concatenate
  them into a single field in a single row with a specified delimiter
  between.
- Do yet another Spatial Join. This time target is your original roads,
  join features is the layer you've been working on (if you had to use
  Summary Statistics and just have a table, it will require additional
  steps to get back to having geometry to Spatially Join). This time it
  will be a join operation of one-to-one with a match option of
  are_identical_to. In the field map box, remove *all* fields except
  Name (the original one) and CrossName. In that same box, right-click
  CrossName and choose properties. Change the Merge Rule dropdown to
  Join and enter a character that isn't part of any street name
  (hopefully something simple like &). Note you can right-click
  CrossName and access the Merge Rule there, but unless you go into
  properties you can't set the delimiting character. Click ok to do the
  join, and in the resulting feature class you should have a field
  (once again with an alias you'll have to remove) that has both cross
  names separated by your delimiter. If the field is null, it's a
  result of a pseudo-node issue outlined above. If there's only one
  name, the road is a dead end that only has a cross street on one end
  (or possibly has a pseudo-node on the other) or there's an offset in the cross street as noted earlier. If there's *more* than
  two names, more than two named streets hit one end or the other.

With either of those methods you now have to split that concatenated field into the two separate cross street name fields you want. You could then add a new field and do it with a field calculation or there may even be a tool for this. I think I saw one while digging around. Note if there *are* more than two named cross streets, there's no way to know which end they belong to (say Baker and Mylock meet at one end of the segment of Creek and Dwyer at the other, you won't know if the label should read Creek between Baker/Mylock and Dwyer or Creek between Mylock and Baker/Dwyer, etc.). For that you'd need to actually pay attention to start and end nodes, which is an entirely different process.

Comment: Thank you. Did the above and it worked out. I also found a solution which I think also works quite well. Will post shortly. Without your help i would not have come to an answer. Thank again.