# Arcpy script- Update cursor error

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1

This is a [follow-up question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/135890/clean-up-attributes) to a previous post.  For some reason the following script in Arcpy does not want execute the command. Please see fields and script below. (All credit to Aaron for the script)

[image]

```
import arcpy, os

fc = 'Segments'

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ["Name", "Name_From", "Name_To", "OID@"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] != None:  # Make sure there are no None type data

            # 1) Split strings by "&" and 2) remove leading/tailing white space
            cleaned = [x.strip() for x in row[1].split("&")] # "Name_From" field
            cleaned2 = [x.strip() for x in row[2].split("&")] # "Name_To" field

            # Tackling the "Name_From" field
            if row[0] in cleaned: # Make sure "Name" is in "Name_From" field
                cleaned.remove(row[0]) # Remove "Name" from field
                if len(cleaned) > 1:
                    new = ' & '.join(cleaned)
                    row[1] = new
                elif len(cleaned) == 1:
                    row[1] = cleaned[0]
                else:
                    print "There was a problem with OID %s" % row[3]

            # Tackling the "Name_To" field
            if row[0] in cleaned2: # Make sure "Name" is in "Name_To" field
                cleaned2.remove(row[0]) # Remove "Name" from field
                if len(cleaned2) > 1:
                    new2 = ' & '.join(cleaned2)
                    row[2] = new2
                elif len(cleaned2) == 1:
                    row[2] = cleaned2[0]
                else:
                    print "There was a problem with OID %s" % row[3]
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: In your original example you did not have quotation marks--but you do in this example--I suspect that is the issue. (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/135890/clean-up-attributes)  You will need to handle how the script deals with quotes.

Comment: As a general rule, I'd recommend wrapping code like this in a try/except block. And as a general forum practice, if you're posting about an error, it's helpful to include the error.

Comment: Yes this was generated by ArcMap by itself. I will try and find a way too remove the quotation marks. I suspected that this might be the problem. Thank you Aaron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove all of the quotes from your strings.  Here is one approach:

```
# 1) Split strings by "&" and 2) remove leading/tailing white space
cleaned = [x.strip().replace("\"","") for x in row[1].split("&")] # "Name_From" field
cleaned2 = [x.strip().replace("\"","") for x in row[2].split("&")] # "Name_To" field


# Continue with script
```

Comment: Thank you Aaron. This worked perfectly. I am still learning all there is to ArcPy and you have helped immensely.