# Planarize tool in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, editing

Is there a way to use the Planarize Tool (Editing tool) in a ArcPy script.

I want to create a script for a question I posted and with the help of the community resolved that problem. Please see the link:

[Populate cross street name at intersections](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/134693/populate-cross-street-name-at-intersections)

I would like to automate this process but using the Planarize tool is a necessity in the process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this function with the Feature to Line (Data Management) geoprocessing tool which will split lines when they intersect each other:

"Where input lines or polygon boundaries touch, cross, or overlap each other at locations other than their start and end vertices, they will be split at those intersections"

[Desktop Help Feature to Line][1]
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000039000000

Comment: You should probably mention that this requires an Advanced level license, which is still the case at ArcGIS 10.4.1.

Comment: Which means that it doesn't answer the question, as Planarize Lines only requires a Standard licence.