# Dissolving/connecting discontinuous Sewerage network using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, editing, dissolve

I am using ArcMap/ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.

I have a sewerage network that is cut at specific locations and I would like to have a continuous network while retaining the different segment because they have different id's.

Someone have any ideas?

[image]

The Extend Line Work, but some time it doesn't work correctly like the next example:

Before Extend line:

[image]

After the Extend Line :

[image]

Why it didn't take the line just beside-it and it went looking for a line further?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [Integrate](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/integrate.htm) tool but it will probably only work on very small gaps or mess upp your data. Backup your data prior to running the tool.

> Integrate is used to maintain the integrity of shared feature
>   boundaries by making features coincident if they fall within the
>   specified x,y tolerance. Features that fall within the specified x,y
>   tolerance are considered identical or coincident.

You can also take a look at [Geodatabase topology rules and fixes for polyline features](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/editing/geodatabase-topology-rules-for-polyline-features.htm), for example rule [Must Not Have Dangles](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/editing/geodatabase-topology-rules-for-polyline-features.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_D111AE311AFB4DE4ABA90BC12EE8C605):

> The end of a line must touch any part of one other line or any part of
>   itself within a feature class or subtype. Use this rule when you want
>   lines in a feature class or subtype to connect to one another, for
>   example, when a street network has line segments that connect. In this
>   example, you can set exceptions to this rule for road segments that
>   end at cul-de-sacs or terminate with dead-ends.

Or tool [Extend Line](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/editing-toolbox/extend-line.htm):

> This tool extends line segments to the first intersecting feature
>   within a specified distance. If no intersecting feature is within the
>   specified distance, the line segment will not be extended. Tool use is
>   intended for quality control tasks such as cleaning up topology errors
>   in features that were digitized without having set proper snapping
>   environments.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, I tried integrate but it didn't work. For the topology I didn't understand what I must do and where.

Comment: @Loubnabarra Ok. I think you should take the time to learn how to use topology. Start by reading the help section of ArcMap. You can also take a look at my answer to this question (in your case you will need to apply another topology rule): https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/226999/adding-vertices-to-existing-lines-where-they-intersect-using-arcpy/228664#228664

Comment: @Loubnabarra, try tool Extend Line

Comment: I used the topology with all the instructions, but it doesn't work.

I use the Extend Line, but it's been running for over 4 hours and it's still running.

Answer (score 0):

The Extend Line Work, but some time it doesn't work correctly like the next example:

Befor Extend line:

[image]

After the Extend Line :

[image]

Why it didn't take the line just beside-it and it went looking for a line further?

Comment: Could you please [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/244808/edit) your **question** to include these new details instead of posting it as an _answer_? :)